# Python: is there a one-liner to get the last day of the current month?

Tags: python, date, calendar

I want to get the last day of the current month as cleanly as possible.

I am thinking something like `datetime.datetime.last_date_current_month()` in a similiar fashion of `datetime.datetime.today()`

`datetime.date.today().replace(month=datetime.date.today().month +1, day=1) - relativedelta(days=1)`

works but is horrible :)